# View not updating in tabbar app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've been working on a tabbar app that has a bug that has me stumped (still).

When I move into a new tab, data stored in the model part of the app is not used by the view, which thus displays stale info (a graph, numbers, etc.).  I've tried two ways of forcing an update, which is handled in the view by `[self updateDisplay]`.  (1) In the app delegate, use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method to determine which tab is selected, then send it an update message.  Here is a piece of the body of the delegate method:

```
if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]) {
    NSLog(@"graphViewController selected, graphViewController = %@", graphViewController);
    [graphViewController updateDisplay];                    
}
```

This is the way I would like to do the job.  However, the display is not updated, though NSLog confirms that updateDisplay has fired.

(2) Press a button in the view to update the display by executing `[self updateDisplay]`.  This works, but is not satisfactory. Now comes the fun part.  In the log below, we read (1) the delegate method is called, (2) the `graphViewController` is selected, and (3) the graphViewController's updateDisplay method is called.  Great! But `barGraph` is null at this point, and the display including labels that are read from floats in `ourLog` is not updated.  The object `ourLog` is part of the model and it is synchronized with a file on "disk".  (`barGraph` is updated from `ourLog` via `updateDisplay`).

Moving on, we are now in the view managed by GraphViewController, we push the "test" button (6), `updateDisplay` is called, the view is properly updated.

Notice that in 1--5, `GraphViewController` was at 0x4e346e0, whereas in 6--9 it was at 0x4b53c80.  If you toggle back and forth, tabbing out and in, pressing the "test" button, you always get the hex numbers. At first I thought that somehow there were two instances of `GraphViewController` floating around.  But I overrode that class's `init` method so as to log it.  It only shows up once.  So I am totally stumped.

-- Jim

- 1] UITabBarControllerDelegate method called, self =
- 2] graphViewController selected, graphViewController =
- 3] GraphViewController, updateDisplay called, self =
- 4] ourLog:
- 5] updateDisplay, barGraph: (null)
- 6] test pushed
- 7] GraphViewController, updateDisplay called, self =
- 8] ourLog:
- 9] updateDisplay, barGraph: >

PS.  I originally posted this at [UIVIew subclass object becomes mysteriously nil in tabbar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456250/uiview-subclass-object-becomes-mysteriously-nil-in-tabbar-app). I'm posting this anew because the problem is more general that `barGraph` being null at various points in the apps lifecycle. Somehow stuff that needs to be accessible when I call it is not, so I have to figure out a different way to call it.  But it doesn't disappear (I also overrode `dealloc` and didn't find that `barGraph` was ever released).

**Addendum 1: BarGraph.**

Here is how barGraph is created in GraphViewController:

```
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController {

BarGraph *barGraph;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BarGraph *barGraph;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *testButton;

- (void) updateDisplay;
- (IBAction) testAction: (id) sender;

@end
```

In `@implementation`, `viewDidLoad` alloc-inits barGraph:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"xx:BARGRAPH: alloc-init in viewDidLoad, GraphBar");
    barGraph = [[BarGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 140, 289, 130)];
    [self.view addSubview:barGraph];    
    [self updateDisplay];
}
```

Finally, here is the implementation of `updateDisplay`:

```
- (void) updateDisplay {

    // Check to see where GraphViewController is:
    NSLog(@"GraphViewController, updateDisplay called, self = %@", self);

    // Get a pointer to the current data to graph
    Log *ourLog = [self theDelegate].currentLog

    // Log info
    NSLog(@"ourLog: %@", ourLog);
    NSLog(@"updateDisplay, barGraph: %@", self.barGraph);

    // Get the current data out of ourLOg
    self.barGraph.data = ourLog.log;
    // And ask barGraph to display it
    [barGraph setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

**Addendum 2: viewWillAppear.**

I added `viewWillAppear` to `GraphViewController.m` as follows:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"xx: GraphViewController, viewWillAppear has fired");
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self updateDisplay];
}
```

This would seem like the normal and best solution, but this `viewWillAppear` never fires.  Note the method `testAction`, which is activated by a button:

```
- (IBAction) testAction: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"test pushed");
    [self updateDisplay];
}
```

Pushing the button that it is wired to properly updates the display.  But of course I want iOS to push the button, not me:-)

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewController that manages that tab should have a reference to your custom UIView. In your UIViewController's -viewWillAppear method, you can call -updateDisplay. I'm assuming that barGraph is the reference to your custom view. If you are creating it in your xib, just make sure you hook it up to your IBOutlet and that your @property for that outlet is set to retain. If you aren't creating barGraph in your xib then I assume you are creating it in your viewDidLoad. Either way, make sure you set it to your @property.

If you aren't creating it either way, then how are you creating it?

Comment: Hi, I'm creating an instance of barGraph in GraphViewController progrmatically (barGraph is a custom view that I've used in other apps).  I've posted some of the relevant code above in addendum 1.  I've also experimented with viewWillAppear, but it seems never to be called.  I will look at this again.  Thanks!

Comment: I inserted viewWillAppear per Addendum 2 above.  Alas, it never fires.  If I could get it to do so, this would probably solve my problem.

Comment: I can manually fire it by calling it in from the UITabBarDelegate method -- but when the GraphViewController's viewWillAppear fires, subsequently calling updateDisplay, the old problem is creating in a slightly different way.  I believe that iOS has to call this method.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650545/update-uiviewcontrollers-after-switching-of-the-tabbar-selection and checked it out.  Class name is correctly set in IB.  Still stumped!

Comment: Perhaps this is why `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` do not fire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308985/viewdidappear-viewwillappear-not-firing-in-tabbar-app ("technical the view is still visible" that is, behind another one).  If so, then I will have to look for another solution to getting `updateDisplay` to fire at the right moment.  For it does work when manually activated by pushing a button, but not when called from the delegate at the moment one has selected the new tab.  Hmmmmm!